# Phantom white space between 2 <li>s

Tags: html, css

built a simple no-dropdown horizontal nav for a new site design and its all working fine like normal except that between 2 buttons is a phantom white space that doesn't appear in dragonfly's metrics, or in the code, but is visible on the screen when the li's hover rule applies. and it does not appear between each li, just between 2 specific lis. i have attached images below showing what i mean:

no problem, everything looks as it should:
[image: No Problem]

on the right side of the hovered li is a px of whitespace that shouldnt be there:
[image: Problem]

```css
    .navi {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 50px;
      max-height: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      list-style: none;
      float: right;
    }
    .navi li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navi li a {
      padding: 16px;
      border-left: 1px solid #8bd854;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 50px;
      color: #8c8c8c;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .navi li a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(13, 137, 0, 0.61);
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navi">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Lawn Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Tree &amp; Shrub Removal</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

any idea where this may be coming from? It's not a huge deal if not Solvable but it is an annoyance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Do you know what browser(s) this is happening on? I tried copying that code to a fiddle and it rendered fine in Chrome and IE. There might be more to it than what you've presented. Any relevant links that can be used to replicate the behavior?

Comment: @Xufox The `li` are floated...not inline-block.

Comment: @Quantastical Firefox chrome and IE for me. you can actually see it in example if youd like https://stuart-robert.codio.io/

Comment: No issue here on FF/Chrome/IE/Opera (Win8)

Comment: I suspect there's more to the CSS that's causing the problem. What does your browser's web inspector say about the element in question? There's probably something else adding padding to it.

Comment: hmm @sodawillow interesting

Comment: By any chance does this depend on browser zoom level?

Comment: I've run into this too.  Not sure what's causing it, but try adding `display:block` to `.navi li a` and changing `padding: 16px` to `padding: 0 16px` on that same rule.

Comment: It apparently only happens when the browser is a very specific sizes. For example, I can see the white space on 1771px wide Chrome, but its not there on 1770px wide Chrome. Very interesting issue. At first glance, I suspect this to be a graphical rendering glitch.

Comment: @miken32 there isnt though. the inspector (dragonfly) shows margins and padding as normal, and if i simulate a hover with dragonfly the whitespace does not show up.

Comment: Can confirm @JosephMarikle solution works.

Comment: fwiw, hover is fine in FF 41 Mac

Comment: I'd guess this is due to pixel rounding.

Comment: @JosephMarikle this works perfectly! please add that as an answer and ill accept it as the solution

Comment: @JLGriffin I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this.  Maybe it's webkit or some nuance of CSS, but at least in this one particular case, you can add `display:block` to `.navi li a` and change `padding: 16px` to `padding: 0 16px` on that same rule.  Unfortunately I can't figure out why this works but my best guess is that whitespace is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to fix this is by using the `font-size`:

```
.navi {
    font-size: 0;
}

.navi li {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

This sets the font size of the list to zero and the font size of the list element to the size of the root element (you may use any other unit – except `em` – if you want to).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue in Chrome by setting the zoom to 110%.  Perhaps, you could set the zoom of all the navigation elements and their children to be `zoom: 1.0;`.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably just whitespace. try

```
<ul class="navi"
  ><li><a href="">Home</a></li
  ><li><a href="">About</a></li
  ...
></ul>
```